# Ensuring that two Request Mapping variables match in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have the following `@RequestMapping` within my Spring MVC controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{personId}/rtbc-{personId}-badge.pdf", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView produceBadgePdf(@PathVariable Integer personId){
    // rest of the code
}
```

My question is: How can I ensure that the two `personId`s in the `@RequestMapping` are matching Integers? Should I just make the variable names differ? Or could I keep the variable names the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would change these to seperate integers so you can compare them and end up with the below.  Given your example above this should cause no problems and you wouldn't need to edit any client side code of the request either.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{personId}/rbc-{secondPersonId}-badge.pdf", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView produceBadgePdf(@PathVariable Integer personId, @PathVariable Integer secondPersonId){
    if(secondPersonId !=null && secondPersonId.equals(personId)) { }
}
```

Comment: You'd better use secondPersonId.equals(personId)

Comment: It was just a quick example but I've changed it so it's both .equals and won't throw a NPE, either way it's academic.

Comment: Remember the != null on the secondPersonId in case the user only sends one value through so it doesn't throw a NPE :3